# VBA Loop search by text,offset then incremnt

Tags: vba, excel

I've been searching for more than 3 days to build this VBA Macro I need so any help would be much I appreciated.I want to build a macro with a Loop that will search for certain fixed text (this will be my reference step text) in a column let us say it's Column C, once it find that text will offset to the next cell to the left in Column B and this cell will have a variable text that I want to copy down to just before the next text step of C. I think Macro will be by making double loops, first loop to search for the text in column C and once find it will offset to adjacent cell of column B then another loop to copy & paste the value of cell of column B down to before the next text step of C and first loop will be performed on all column c. my trial with first loop was some how successful as I tried to make it either with identifying the certain text as a Boolean or using For Each loop. but my hard part was always in the second loop to increment the text of column B down to the cell before the next step of column C and relate the two loops to each other.
Below are my trials if you could help in them I would be much appreciated.

```
    Sub test()

    Dim i As Long

    Dim ilastrow As Long

    Dim n As string

    ilastrow = Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
Dim r As Range, cell As Range
Set r = Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row

For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value = "TH" Then
   ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-1).Activate
n = ActiveCell.Value
'from here I want to copy n down to every cell until before next "TH" in column C then proceed with next "TH" as n will be changed and so on for all "TH" in Colmun C 

End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[what I want to do with picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4iz7.jpg)

any help will be much appreciated thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Option Explicit


Sub test()

  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = ActiveSheet

  With sht
    Dim ilastrow As Long
    ilastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim r As Range, cell As Range, prevCell As Range
    Set r = .Range("C1:C" & ilastrow)

    Set prevCell = Nothing
    For Each cell In r
      If cell.Value = "TH" Then
        If Not prevCell Is Nothing Then
          prevCell.Offset(1, -1).Resize(cell.Row - prevCell.Row - 1, 1).Value = prevCell.Offset(, -1).Value
          Set prevCell = cell
        Else
          Set prevCell = cell
        End If
      End If
    Next

    ilastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    prevCell.Offset(1, -1).Resize(ilastrow - prevCell.Row, 1).Value = prevCell.Offset(, -1).Value

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works great thanks alot much appreciated your help, the only issue I faced that is stops at the last "TH" in column "C" and won't proceed to the previous cell next to last "TH" in column "B". If you can modify it to proceed also to last previous cell in column B  and copy it untill to last cell in anthor column like column "A" or even to last of column "B". Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When you say `won't proceed to the previous cell next to last "TH" in column "B"` do you mean you want to also copy cells in A the way they are in column B?  If you post a picture of what you want I should be able to change the code accordingly.

Comment: Thankssssssssss alot works great, your Help is much appropriated :)